# What does "?" meaning in /etc/shadow file in RHEL

Tags: linux, shadow

What does `?` meaning in `/etc/shadow` file in RHEL in second column?

```
myuser:**?**:17968:0:99999:7:::
```

I could find answer for `X`, `*`, `!`, but not for `?`.

Comment: See @KamilMaciorowski 's refrence, but be aware that it is a bit hidden that `?` has the same effect as `!` or `*` and only hashes with characters from `[a-zA-Z0-9./]` are allowed (making `?` illegal). See `man shadow` and `man 3 crypt`

Comment: @FelixJN, except for the algorithm markers and separators that have `$` signs, and I think the shacrypt Linux hashes also take arguments like `rounds=1234` or so.

Comment: The accepted answer for the duplicated question quotes a text saying "If the password field contains some string that is not a valid result of crypt(3) [...]".  The character `?` is such a string ("boogabooga" is used as an example in the duplicate's duplicate).